# What is the gender distribution of mice in seven generations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A population of mice begins with four males and four females. When a heterosexual couple mates, they have an equal chance of producing a male or a female offspring. However, once they produce the first female is born, then the couple becomes barren. What is the gender distribution of mice in seven generations?

Teacher said I can either solve by brute force, or see through the puzzle.  I am at a loss with either way.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93830/expected-number-of-ratio-of-girls-vs-boys-birth)

Comment: @ThomasBladt I have read through it briefly, thank you very much!  I will sit down with the proofs in a bit.